# R: unshared elements across multiple vectors (opposite to intersect)

Tags: r, intersection, overlap, difference

I want to extract all the shared elements and unshared elements between multiple vectors.

Say I have these vectors:

```
set.seed(9)
a <- sample(LETTERS,10,replace=F)
b <- sample(LETTERS,10,replace=F)
c <- sample(LETTERS,10,replace=F)
```

I first explore their overlap with a Venn diagram:

```
venn.diagram(list('a'=a,'b'=b,'c'=c), filename="test.png", height=1000, width=1000, imagetype="png", units="px")
```

[image: test]

I know how to obtain the elements shared by all the vectors (the central 3), this way:

```
shared <- Reduce(intersect, list(a,b,c))
length(shared)#3, correct
```

However, how can I obtain the unshared elements across the groups (5+7+5=17)?

My attempt is the following:

```
outersect <- function(a,b) unique(c(setdiff(a,b), setdiff(b,a)))
unshared <- Reduce(outersect, list(a,b,c))
length(unshared)#20, I expect 17 (5+7+5)
```

But the number is incorrect, since comparisons are made on a pairwise basis... Any idea to do this easily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My approach would be to combine all those vector first.
then count frequency with table function and lastly calculate the length

```
temp = c(a,b,c)
temp_table = table(temp)
length(temp_table[temp_table == 1])
```

and use names if you want to show the unique element

```
names(temp_table[temp_table == 1])
```

Comment: Of course using table! Thanks, this is really intuitive

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
lapply(1:3,function(i){
  sets[[i]][!sets[[i]] %in%  Reduce(union,sets[i != c(1,2,3)],init = NULL)]
  })
```

making a union of the vectors not used and checking which element of the other vector is not in the union